# Using Boolean AND on Linux File Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, boolean

I want to check whether a file on Linux has permission 555, but the file has a 755 permission instead.
So I do a boolean AND in my program:

```
if ((perm_of_file && perm_required) == 555)
```

i.e. `(755 && 555 == 555)`

Should this evaluate to true?
I know this is not intuitive from a programming prospective and the real background question is:
**Is 755 considered as a "member" of the 555 permission group?**

What I tried:
I use `find -perm 555` on Linux and it doesn't list those files who has 755 permission, so I am guessing the answer to the question is NO?

If somebody can help me answer or rephrase this question, that would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if ((perm_of_file & perm_required) == 0555)` or, even better : `if ((perm_of_file & perm_required) == perm_required)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ((file_mode && some_bits) == some_bits) # is *logical* and, you need bitwise and
- ((file_mode & some_bits) == some_bits)  # is *bitwise* and
- file modes are (still) expressed in *octal* notation, in most C-like languages you'll need to add a leading zero to indicate octal mode
- command-line programs (such as chmod or find) don't need the leading zero, they expect the numerical mode-string to be octal
- find . -mode xxx # finds files with *exactly* the mode xxx
- find . -mode -xxx # finds files with *at least* the mode bits xxx set

Comment: I tried use find -perm -555 and it list all files that has at least 555 permission, work as expected

Comment: However, `755 & 555` give me the results of `547`, shouldn't it be 555?

Comment: `(0755 & 0555)` should yield 0555. Remember: it's octal.

Comment: Thanks, that works, I forget to include the `0` in front of it

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Because in 755 the owner of the file has write permission and in 555 owner has no write permission. (Although owner can change it with `chmod` because he's the owner!).

As I see you want to check whether one permission is *inclusive* in another one. If you somehow have the permissions of the files, then simply check:

`if (perm_of_file >= perm_required)`

Comment: By combining your answer to @wildplasser's answer, I get a perfect one. Thank you for the clarification !